# Export an angular module as a commonjs module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm writing an angular module that i want to make it work with requirejs,
This is an example:

```
(function (){
    'use strict';

    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])

    .directive('myDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                item:    '=',
            },
            template: '<span>Item: {{ item }}</span>'
        };
    }]);

  if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = myModule;
  }

})();
```

Is this a good approach, if not, how should i export this, to make it work correctly?

Comment: With requirejs or common modules (ie. browserify)?

Comment: commonjs @elclanrs sorry for not being so clear.

Answer (score 2):

Registering an angular module is a side-effect. What you can do is export the name:

```
var name = 'myModule';

angular.module(name, [])

.directive('myDirective', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      item:    '=',
    },
    template: '<span>Item: {{ item }}</span>'
  };
}]);

module.exports = name;
```

Then you can require it in another module, for example:

```
angular.module('app', [
  require('./path/to/myModule') // runs side-effect (registers the module)
])
```

Comment: how would you avoid having the `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` warning if you are using the directive on no CommonJS enviroment?

Comment: @ChristianGill: Browserify has an option `--standalone` that will convert your module to UMD.